# I get blank pages for validated AMP pages

Tags: amp-html

My amp pages is valid by test tools and shown in google search with lightning bolt symbol when I googled with keywords.
I also had registered/fetched urls for the amp pages in new and old Search Consoles. New search console said it was crawled successfully.
Of course, those amp pages are properly shown on mobile as amp pages when I directly visit the amp urls.
And for more info, validator in "https://ampbench.appspot.com/" shows proper cache when I clicked the result link in '[PASS] [HTTP: 200] URL is indexed in the Google AMP Cache:', no problems.

But I have problems.

1. It looks like not "properly" indexed, because it is not listed when
   I google "site:myampurl".
2. The link in google search results is
       corrupted like the image below. Probably, I have to wait another few days, but even so, current situation is not good.

How can I solve this issue?
[image]

[edit]
I don't use google tag manager. And AMP pages are not registered on my sitemap, only responsive PC pages which is MFIed, is listed on the sitemap. I mainly develop and test the pages on Mac, and iOS. My AMP pages are just single static pages, not dynamically created, not wordpressed.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have set some redirection on the page https://www.rockstarcoders.com/ruby_on_rails_developers that is why it may come like this way. Because the pages has got indexed in AMP but in your original site, it got redirected so on the AMP pages related to /ruby_on_rails_developers got no content. That is why it is not showing black page for that URL, have tried your other AMP pages??

Comment: that image is not from my site, it's just example because the blank page and upper design on the blank page are exact same as my issue. My other AMP pages in the domain are fine.

Comment: Google's search results shows still same. It says the article is (cached) 6 days ago, and the link is like https://www.google.co.jp/amp/s/(mypagepath) and it shows the same image I posted. The day  '6 days ago' is when the AMP page is uploaded and fetched as google, so it might be corrupted in google server, because, in contrast, validator in "https://ampbench.appspot.com/" shows proper cache.

Comment: If you can share the URL, that would be great. Otherwise there will be only assumptions regarding the issue.

Comment: It solved. I was right. I have to wait another few days. So  for nearly a week the pages were corrupted. Only reason I can think about, except possible google's bugs, is that rel="amphtml" was added few days later for those canonical pages.

Comment: Today, again the link is corrupted. So google's AMP seems to be unstable. On desktop mobile mode, it shows blank page for the first visit, and then it shows AMP pages for second and later visit. On phone, it shows non-AMP page for the seach results now.

Comment: Make sure that your that particular page is indexed properly with Google search console in AMP section. Can you tell me, from where you came to know that your AMP page was cached 6 days ago??

Comment: I make sure that. And you always can see when the pages were cached with two ways. FIrst way is to use AMP section on new search console, the second way is to look at google search results' cached-day info.